# Grunt command no longer recognized

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have this issue where my grunt is not recognized as a command anymore. I have looked for a solution but most problems are saying I need to use the CLI which I already am. I am on a computer where I have node.js installed and I am currently using it in the project I was before, so no changes on the folder it is in.

```
C:\Users\fmeloni\Dropbox\Transfer\BananaUnified\sources\Banana>grunt dev
'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\fmeloni\Dropbox\Transfer\BananaUnified\sources\Banana>grunt --help
'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried reinstalling npm based on this page : http://gruntjs.com/getting-started but I have warnings now.

```
C:\Users\fmeloni\Dropbox\Transfer\BananaUnified\sources\Banana>npm install
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /grunt-ts/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@0.3.8
npm WARN Innodirect@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

I then tried the grunt CLI which resulted in this :

```
C:\Users\fmeloni\Dropbox\Transfer\BananatUnified\sources\Banana>npm install -g grunt-cli
C:\Users\fmeloni\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt -> C:\Users\fmeloni\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt
C:\Users\fmeloni\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- grunt-cli@1.2.0
```

I have not used the grunt commands for 1 week so there might have been windows update, but there is no new programs installed on my machine. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this or what is the meaning of those warnings with the npm install.

Comment: To keep this post up to date, I have updated my nom to version 4.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a path issue so I just needed to add to my path `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`

I am unsure why it disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [closed issue](https://github.com/ariesjia/grunt-riot/issues/16) that hints to a problem with win 10. There seem to be two solutions.

A few solved with:

```
npm update --no-optional
```

Others with:

```
rmdir node_modules /s /q
npm i
```

Do they solve it for you?

Comment: Sadly they did not, the update one did nothing at all though, if it helps.

Comment: What version of node and npm are you using?

Comment: Npm 3.6.0 and node 5.6.0 I got those number with npm version so I am unsure if they are right.

Comment: I just checked and [there are others](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1435) in your condition with bleeding edge version of node/npm. I feel this could be a regression in fsevent and/or npm.

Comment: Thank you, I will add it here if I find a solution